# Jetty-runner.jar set request timeout

Tags: heroku, timeout, jetty

Is there a parameter setting that I can pass when running jetty-runner.jar to configure the request timeout?

Ex:

```
java $JAVA_OPTS -jar server/jetty-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```

I'm trying to deploy an application on Heroku using grails and is having a difficult time figuring out how to increase the server request timeout. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The max request length (30 seconds) is set by the Heroku router, not Jetty Runner. For more info, see:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout